# Add constraint to prevent NaN in a table

Tags: postgresql, constraints, nan

I have a column that has the form `myVar REAL NOT NULL`. This column should only ever contain actual numbers. What kind of constraint can I add to prevent `myVar` from becoming NaN?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually you need a special function to detect if a value is NaN (similar to requiring `is null` and `is not null` tests for SQL's `null`) but in PostgreSQL, [`NaN = NaN` is true](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL):

> [...] In order to allow numeric values to be sorted and used in tree-based indexes, PostgreSQL treats `NaN` values as equal, and greater than all non-`NaN` values.

So a simple CHECK constraint with a direct comparison is sufficient:

```
check (myvar <> 'NaN')
```

You can include a cast if you like but it isn't necessary:

```
check (myvar <> 'NaN'::real)
check (myvar <> 'NaN'::numeric)
```